# Prevent changing the length of post_name column on WordPress Update

Tags: database, slug, updates, upgrade

We've some Arabic websites running on WordPress, and use Arabic slugs in the posts' URLs.

You know that post slug is stored in the `post_name` column in `wp_posts` table, and the default length of this column is `200` characters, which is not enough for Arabic slugs that are being encoded before being stored in this column. For that, we changed the length of this column to `1000` characters to hold the long encoded slugs that we have.

The issue, when we update the WordPress code to a major update, it trims this column back to `200` characters, and this breaks the posts' URLs. This happens if you login for the first time after the update to the CMS or do a **Network Upgrade** that is prompted after each major update.

Is there any way to prevent WordPress from touching the tables' structure?

### UPDATE

I tried to run a SQL query after the Network Upgrade to alter the `post_name` column, but I got a SQL syntax error, while I didn't get any issue when running the same query using the DB console.

Here's my code:

```php
function after_network_upgrade() {
    global $wpdb;
    // Get the length of the `post_name` column in the `posts` table.
    $query = $wpdb->prepare(  "
        SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE 
            TABLE_NAME   = '%s' AND 
            COLUMN_NAME  = 'post_name'
        ", $wpdb->base_prefix.'posts' );
    $post_name_max_length = $wpdb->get_results($query)[0]->CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH;
    // if the length is set to the default value `200`, then do the fix.
    if ($post_name_max_length == 200) {
        $wpdb->query("
            ALTER TABLE wp_posts   MODIFY `post_name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_2_posts MODIFY `post_name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_3_posts MODIFY `post_name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_4_posts MODIFY `post_name` VARCHAR(1000) NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_terms   MODIFY `slug`      VARCHAR(500)  NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_2_terms MODIFY `slug`      VARCHAR(500)  NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_3_terms MODIFY `slug`      VARCHAR(500)  NULL;
            ALTER TABLE wp_4_terms MODIFY `slug`      VARCHAR(500)  NULL;
            UPDATE wp_posts   SET `post_name` = `post_name_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_2_posts SET `post_name` = `post_name_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_3_posts SET `post_name` = `post_name_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_4_posts SET `post_name` = `post_name_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_terms   SET `slug`      = `slug_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_2_terms SET `slug`      = `slug_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_3_terms SET `slug`      = `slug_copy`;
            UPDATE wp_4_terms SET `slug`      = `slug_copy`;"
        );
        if ($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
            print "<p class='wpdberror'><strong>WordPress database error:</strong><code>";
            print_r ($wpdb->last_error);
            print "</code><br /></div>";
        } else {
            print "<div>The length of the `post_name` column length is FIXED!</div>";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'after_mu_upgrade', 'after_network_upgrade', 10, 1 );
```

The `post_name_copy` and `slug_copy` are custom columns that keep a backup of the `post_name` and `slug` values to use when the issue happens.

And this is the printed SQL error I got:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE wp_2_posts MODIFY post_name VARCHAR(1000) NULL; ALTER ' at line 2`

Any help on this, please?

Comment: Hi Jafar! Did you find a solution for this? I have the exact same issue and I'll be happy if you share what you do to handle it 

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I had a quick look at some of the upgrade code and noticed that a very old upgrade function rewrites the post_name using the `sanitize_title` function, and that calls `sanitize_title_with_dashes`, and that contains this bit of code:

```
  if ( seems_utf8( $title ) ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtolower' ) ) {
      $title = mb_strtolower( $title, 'UTF-8' );
    }
    $title = utf8_uri_encode( $title, 200 );
  }
```

Note that this is pretty interesting because *only* if the function `mb_strtolower` is not available will this code cause the string to become truncated to 200 characters!

You could do a quick check on your system to see if you have the PHP multibyte string extension installed, because if you don't, then sanitize title will truncate your titles, and so **maybe** you can solve your problem by installed the PHP multibyte extension.

To check if that's the case, have a look at `phpinfo();`, or just run this somewhere directly on your server:

```
if ( function_exists( 'mb_strtolower' ) ) {
   echo "yes mb strings installed";
} else {
   echo "no mb strings not installed";
}
```

**Please note**: There's too much code for me to validate that this is definitely what's happening in your case. Someone else may have a definite answer. The '200' value which aligns perfectly with what's happening for you seems like a good indiciation that this could be the issue, but I didn't find any specific place where this is called on every single upgrade.

Comment: Thank you @mozboz for your help, but the `mbstring` module was activated when I did the upgrade, and the same issue happened, the `post_name` column was truncated to `200`.